# Bash auto completion not working after certain command

Tags: command-line, bash, cygwin, autocomplete, graphviz

I am using graphViz under bash / Cygwin, but somehow when calling it, bash tab autocomplete does not do anything.

Example files:

- `myGraph.graphviz` is the input file
- `myGraph.graphviz.png` should be the output file.

The command to make the graphic is

```
dot -T png -o myGraph.graphviz.png myGraph.graphviz
```

Of course I want to input

```
dot -T png -o myTab.png myTab
```

to autocomplete these file names, but nothing happens! I can enter `cat myTab` and it gives `cat myGraph.graphviz`, but why doesn't it work after `dot`? Does bash need an extra autocomplete module for every command I could enter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created the example files in my Debian. Indeed, `dot -T png -o myTab` doesn't work. Then (after completing manually) `dot -T png -o myGraph.graphviz.png myTab` also doesn't work. There are two separate issues.

---

[The general manual](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/command.html) for Graphviz programs specifies:

> `-ooutfile`
>   Write output to file *outfile*. […]

Bash completion in my Debian obeys this literally: it supports `-ooutfile`, not `-o outfile`. Even if the latter works with `dot` (and I don't know this), the completion doesn't support it. You should proceed like this:

```
dot -T png -omyTab
```

without any space after `-o`. In my tests the above works.

---

To make the second <kbd>Tab</kbd> work I inspected `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/dot`. The relevant line near the end is:

```
_filedir dot
```

This will offer you directories to descend into and files to specify, but only files with names ending with `.dot` or `.DOT`. Probably you can *manually* provide a file not matching this pattern and nothing bad will happen, yet if you rely on the completion mechanism then the file name should end properly.

In fact I don't know `dot` at all, I know Bash completions a little. Maybe the requirement doesn't make sense and the completion for `dot` would be more helpful if it allowed *any* file. In such case I copy the original file to `/etc/bash_completion.d/` and modify the copy, so the line

```
_filedir dot
```

at the end of the function becomes

```
_filedir
```

This is a system-wide change. The change will not affect existing shells, so start a new `bash` to test it. If you cannot (or don't want to) modify `/etc/bash_completion.d/` then see [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/831184). It provides a way to have your private (user-specific) `bash_completion.d/`.

Note this change will allow you to type `dot -T png -o myTab` and the completion will work. However in this particular case it has nothing to do with `-o` internally, it's the general completion for operands and it would work even after some unexpected or invalid option (e.g. `dot -T png -: myTab`).

Comment: This is cool, I did not know `dot` wants a `dot` file. I just edited the line in `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/dot`, since this is my personal cygwin installation, and it works!!

Comment: @Bowi OK. In general I expect files in `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/` to be updated without warning (if you ever update/upgrade), so your edit may be reverted in the future. A copy in `/etc/bash_completion.d/` will most likely stay untouched.

Comment: *Very* good point. Copied it. =)

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if there is another `dot` command on the system for which a real autocomplete definition is installed, and that command doesn't expect a file at that point. You get file auto-completion on all parameters by default for unknown commands, but specific commands can set their own specific auto-completion. Check `/etc/bash_completion` and `/etc/bash_completion.d/`.

PS: Another explanation is that the `dot` auto-completion script isn't coherent with the doc, or that you made a mistake in your arguments.

Comment: I do not have an `/etc/bash_completion`, only a `/etc/bash_completion.d/` with a few files in it. `grep -Ri "dot"` does not bring up anyting though...